# Why am I able to select both radio buttons at the same time?

Tags: html, angular

Why am I able to select both radio buttons at the same time ?

```
  <form #form="ngForm">
    {{ poll.counter1 }} votes <input type="radio" id="{{ poll.choice1 }}" value="{{ poll.choice1 }}" (click)="onChoice1(form)">{{ poll.choice1 }}
    <br>
    {{ poll.counter2 }} votes <input type="radio" id="{{ poll.choice2  }}" value="{{ poll.choice2 }}" (click)="onChoice2(form)">{{ poll.choice2 }}
  </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to only select one, you have to give both radio buttons the same name.

```
<form #form="ngForm">
    {{ poll.counter1 }} votes <input type="radio" name="my_radio" id="{{ poll.choice1 }}" value="{{ poll.choice1 }}" (click)="onChoice1(form)">{{ poll.choice1 }}        
    {{ poll.counter2 }} votes <input type="radio" name="my_radio" id="{{ poll.choice2  }}" value="{{ poll.choice2 }}" (click)="onChoice2(form)">{{ poll.choice2 }}
</form>
```

You can try it here:

```html
<label>Radio A</label>
<input type="radio" name="foo">
<label>Radio B</label>
<input type="radio" name="foo">

<h2>Without the same name</h2>
<label>Radio X</label>
<input type="radio">
<label>Radio Y</label>
<input type="radio">
```